# Understanding react native TextInput state

Tags: react-native

I have two questions regarding how TextInput onChangeText works.

1. How do I decide which parent component of the TextInput should handle state changes?
2. How does the onChangeText prop function get called by that parent component?

1.Let me give a quick code example. Say I have a class component LoginForm using a functional child component Input:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = { text: '' };

  render() {
    return (
      <Input
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
          labelText={'Email:'}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In this case I have created a functional component Input with a child component `<TextInput>` so that Input is reusable. What should influence my choice of whether `<LoginForm>` or `<Input>` should be the class component monitoring state?

2.How does `<LoginForm>` currently have its `setState` functional called? The prop passed is a function referencing `this`, how does it get called inside 2 layers of children? Does this binding to a parent happen to indefinite amount of nested components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your functional component reusable then it would be best to let your parents handle text changes. For example say if your text input handled it's text change in it's own state then every time your form would need to submit the value you would need to fetch the value from the TextInput not to mention it wouldn't mean true reusability since you couldn't adjust the functionality in case the requirement changes, plus by having the TextInput value in your parent's state would allow validation while the user is typing, and since a state change would call render in the parent and you can pass the value down to the component.

When you pass the function as a prop to the functional component you bind it in the parent so when the text input calls the function 'this' refers to the parent instance and calling set state would affect the parent's state.

A little longer than I expected to type but I hope that answers your question.

Comment: thanks! for the first question, it sounds like I need to choose the parent such that no 'fetching' between components is required

Comment: happy to help ! my ideas got messed up in the first one but basically to allow more control and full re usability its best to handle the main logic on the parent side.

Comment: by sending this.setState to a child, is that bind propagated indefinitely? Can I nest an indefinite amount of components and still get access to `this.state`?

Comment: yep as long as you pass that reference down you can access it at any level of nesting...although i should advice if you need to pass the reference more than 2 levels of nesting then you should probably restructure the logic of your application

Comment: I found [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) to be helpful for binding

Comment: Ive read that one before and for the most part its right. Just one thing that most people miss out is that arrow functions are instantiated every time the component loads. Which means that a new function is created every time that component that is given an arrow function is mounted. A better practice is passing method references rather than arrow functions.
[More on binding and arrow functions as props](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)